# Using customized Random number in keypair generation in uECC_make_key method in micro-ecc - Riot OS

Tags: cryptography, key-generator, riot-os, relic

I am trying to implement an elliptic curve scheme in [micro_ecc](http://doc.riot-os.org/group__pkg__micro__ecc.html), wherein the secret key is the addition of two random numbers and the public key is derived from the secret key as follows priv_key = (a+b) public_key = (a+b)G. I have checked the code in micro_ecc the key pair generation is defined in uECC_make_key() in uECC.c but it seems that the implementation cannot be modified to add any new elements. I have run the code in the pkg_micro-ecc-with-hwrng example given in the tests folder. Can someone tell me how I can randomly select the secret key and then generate the key pair as mentioned above? If micro_ecc in Riot does not support it, can I do the same in the [relic](http://doc.riot-os.org/group__pkg__relic.html)?

Comment: why are you messing around with adding numbers for the private scalar generation, why not just use the system csprng?

Comment: I am designing a shared group key scheme that involves the addition of random numbers and then scalar multiplication. I hope it makes sense.